# Latency compensation and Firestore transactions

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, transactions

I have an onSnapshot keeping track of the documents in a collection:

`db.collection('/.../').onSnapshot(querySnapshot=> mylocalvariable = querySnapshot.docs)`

Now, I want to select the first (in some order) element of this collection of documents that my user has not yet handled. When a user is done handling a document, I use a transaction to update the document according to the user's needs (transaction is better for me than .update() because I might have multiple users changing different parts of the document).

The problem is that unlike a .update (which would update mylocalvariable immediately), it seems like the transaction finishes without updating mylocalvariable. So, when I go to grab the "next" document, it just grabs the same document, because the function runs before the variable gets updated.

Code sample:

````
db.collection('/mycollection').onSnapshot(querySnapshot=> mylocalvariable = querySnapshot.docs)

function selectnextrecord(){
  nextrecord = mylocalvariable.find(x=>!x.data().done)
  console.log(nextrecord)
  //expected: Get something different than the current record
  //observed: This is being run with old data, so it returns the same record that I currently have with the old data.
}
let nextrecord;
selectnextrecord();

function submitchanges(){
   let sfDocRef = db.collection('/mycollection').doc(nextrecord.id);
   return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
      return transaction.get(sfDocRef).then(function(sfDoc) {
         if (!sfDoc.exists) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
         }
         transaction.update(sfDocRef, {done:true});
      });
   }).then(function() {
            selectnextrecord();
   }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
   });
}```
````

Comment: Please edit your question to include the minimal, complete code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It would be helpful if you show more of the relevant code here, as well as a more detailed description of the behavior that's confusing to you.  Debug logging is good to see.

Comment: I added some code, but of course you have to run it with some firestore. I hope it clarifies the problem. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#passing_information_out_of_transactions), I think this is expected behavior.

> Do not modify application state inside of your transaction functions. Doing so will introduce concurrency issues, because transaction functions can run multiple times and are not guaranteed to run on the UI thread. Instead, pass information you need out of your transaction functions

In any case, you could filter the documents that are not done with `.where()` and then place your transaction inside a `foreach`:

```
db.collection('cities')
.where("done", "==", true)
.get()
.then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    return db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
      return transaction.get(sfDocRef).then(function(sfDoc) {
         if (!sfDoc.exists) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
         }
         transaction.update(sfDocRef, {done:true});
      });
   }).catch(function(error) {
     console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
   });
  })
})
```

Comment: I only want to mark a document as done once a user has examined it and made any needed changes. If I wrap it in a 'where', doesn't that just do all of them at once? I don't think this is an example of modifying state inside a transaction. That is to avoid something like having a front-end variable numberofcompleteddocuments, and doing numberofcompleteddocuments+=1 inside the transactions, which would give the wrong number if the transaction has to re-run.